# Squid 2.6 and https_port

Tags: ssl, https, centos, squid

I have a question about Squid configuration as trasparent proxy using SSL.

I would to use Squid 2.6 as trasparent proxy with http and https connection.
I followed this steps:

1) I configurated my iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Nov  9 13:37:50 2011
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10363:2864591]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Nov  9 13:37:50 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Nov  9 13:37:50 2011
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4:650]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3129
COMMIT
```

2) I configurated my squid.conf about http_port and it work well.

3) About SSL I setted this:

```
https_port 3129 transparent  key=/etc/squid/ssl/myhost.com-private.pem
cert=/etc/squid/ssl/myhost.com-certificate.pem
```

but about https not work.
If I use this command lsof -n -i -P | grep squid

about the squid I see also:

```
squid     6483   squid    6u  IPv4 155998      0t0  UDP *:43053
squid     6483   squid   13u  IPv4 156001      0t0  TCP *:3128 (LISTEN)
squid     6483   squid   14u  IPv4 156003      0t0  UDP *:3130
```

and I not see 3129 port. Is correct this way?
Any suggestions?